# Business email address not found error

Tags: email, google-workspace, web-hosting

I have set our hosting (CentOS Web Panel) with the MX Record it needs for our business email through G Suite. The problem is it keeps prompting **"Address not found"**. If I search the domain at leafdns.com, an MX Record returns. Why is that? How will I ever receive email? The first time I did this was flawless, now that I did it again I am receiving errors. Thanks

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: The receiving mail server (where the MX record points to) says the email address does not exist. I would check the logs there and verify the configuration.

Comment: @mtak I have inquired to google itself, there was a bug with my mx records. They fixed it already. Thanks for the answer tho